# PHP has permission denied on simlink

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions, symlink

Could I ask for some help with PHP and permissions on Linux. I'm trying to move log files from `/var/www/html/log` to `/home/user/log` and then created symbolic link to it. I have used command

```
ln -s /home/user/log/ log
```

to create the link and made sure to give permissions 755 (even 777) to both link and folder `/home/user/log`, as well as owner set to apache:apache on both. But I get permission denied all the time even if I try to just list the files over the symlink. Tried adding to httpd.conf below:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  # Allow open access:
  Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/user/log">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  # Allow open access:
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

New folder location permissions

```
drwxrwxrwx. 3 apache apache 4.0K Feb 15 11:19  log
```

Symlink permissions

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   17 Feb 15 12:57 log -> /home/user/log/
```

Error from php in chrome browser

```
Warning: scandir(/var/www/html/log): failed to open dir: Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 2
```

`test.php` code

```
<?php
  $files = scandir('/var/www/html/log');
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($files);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output of `ls -ld /home/user /home/user/log`

```
drwxrwxrwx. 28   user user   4096 Feb 15 11:18 /home/user
drwxrwxrwx.  3 apache apache 4096 Feb 15 12:57 /home/user/log
```

What am I missing??

Thank you

Comment: Are you doing the move with PHP code

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, I'm just trying to move log files out of the html home folder, rest of the files will remain. I just want my php files that log stuff to write to files that are in another location.

Comment: Pleae [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. As what user is apache running? Where do you see the error? In a browser / HTTP client? In a log file?  Copy&paste the exact error message. Please show the output of `ls -ld /home/user /home/user/log`. Format error messages or command and output as code blocks, e.g. by using the `{}` tool of the editor field or by inserting `~~~` as a line of its own before and after every code block.

Comment: @Bodo Done as requested

Comment: Did you check for `open_basedir` restrictions?

Comment: @NicoHaase would you mind expanding on that please?

Comment: On what? `open_basedir` restricts the access to some defined folders. Check for that configuration setting to see if there is a path defined

Comment: @NicoHaase that setting is quoted out in my php.ini